# onclick handlers assigned in controller not executed

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field which I'm trying to change the value of by using a plus button and a minus button. The idea is that the `sideController` should assign a function to the `onclick` events which will increment or decrement the number in the `input` element in the model. Then, the model will call the `update` function of its observer objects which will lead to the numbers being updated on the screen in the `input` element.

However, right now, nothing is happening. I don't even get an error message. It seems to me like the onclick event is not assigned properly, because if I place an `alert` inside of the `sideController` file in the `plusButton` function, it doesn't cause an alert on the screen when I click.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar collapse" id="sidebar">
      <div class="noofpeople">
        <div class="row noofpeople-wrapper">
          <input id="numberOfGuests" type="number" class="form-control">
          <button type="button" id="plusButton"></button>
          <button type="button" id="minusButton"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- The application JavaScript code -->  
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/model/dinnerModel.js"></script>
      <script src="js/view/sidebarView.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/sidebarController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

sidebarController.js:

```
var SideController = function(container, model){
    var plusButton = container.find("#plusButton");
    var minusButton = container.find("#minusButton");
    plusButton.onclick = function(){
        alert("hello");
        model.incrNumberOfGuests();
    };
    minusButton.onclick = function(){
        model.decrNumberOfGuests();
    };
};
```

app.js

```
$(function() {
    //We instantiate our model
    var model = new DinnerModel();
    // And create the instance of ExampleView
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    if(sidebar[0] != undefined){
        var sidebarView = new SideBarView(sidebar, model); 
        var sidebarController = new SideController(sidebar, model);
    }

    var dishreel = $("#dishreel");
    if(dishreel[0] != undefined){
        var dishReelView = new DishReelView(dishreel, model);   
    }
});
```

sidebarView.js:

```
var SideBarView = function(container, model){
    var numberOfGuests = container.find("#numberOfGuests");

    numberOfGuests.val(model.getNumberOfGuests);

    this.update = function(){
        numberOfGuests.val(model.getNumberOfGuests());
    }
}
```

dinnerModel.js

```
var DinnerModel = function() {

    //TODO Lab 1 implement the data structure that will hold number of guest
    // and selected dishes for the dinner menu

    var numberOfGuests = 0;

    var selectedDishes = [];

    var observers = []; 

    this.notifyObservers = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i<observers.length; i++){
            observers[i].update();
        }
    }
    this.incrNumberOfGuests = function(){
        numberOfGuests++;
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
    this.decrNumberOfGuests = function(){
        numberOfGuests--;
        this.notifyObservers();
    }

    this.getNumberOfGuests = function() {
        return numberOfGuests;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If I assign the event handler function in app.js, it enters it when I click the button. Why not in `SideController`?

Comment: Check that your code is clean and is well-organized and all the tags are closed because these small things matter.

Comment: In broad strokes it looks like it should work.

Comment: There ya go!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plusButton` is a jQuery object which wraps your DOM element. `onclick` is not a meaningful jQuery property. You can set it, but jQuery won't do anything with that.

To attach a click event handler, you can either access the DOM element directly like so:

```
// Access DOM element directly and set onclick attribute
plusButton[0].onclick = function(){};
```

Or you can use jQuery's `click()` or `on('click')` functions to attach event handlers to all of the DOM elements in the jQuery "array" (0 or more) like so:

```
// Use jQuery's event handling functions
plusButton.click(function(){});
// or
plusButton.on('click', function(){});
```